# Using Theme() to output html/javascript in user edit

Tags: 7, forms, theming

I have a module that outputs a button to the user edit page. I use the form_user_profile_form_alter to append the button but I want to add html and javascript after it. I saw that the theme() function can do this but my attempt does not add any html. Also I saw that the theme needs two parameters but I do not know what the 1st parameter is supposed to be. I was only following examples.

```
function myModule_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  $form['actions']['myButton'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Click Here'
  );
  $form['actions']['myButton']['#submit'][] = 'myModule_callback';

  return $form;
}
```

Here is my callback function

```
function artsci_pubmed_biblio_callback($form,$form_state){
  drupal_set_message('Button Clicked');
  return theme('box', '<li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li><li>Item 3</li>');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to add some markup and Javascript, you don't need a submit callback because that's for handling form submissions.

**Requirement 1: Add html**

Options:

1. [#prefix](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#prefix) and/or [#suffix](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#suffix) form element attributes. (If just simple short html this will do)
2. [#theme](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#theme) to use you custom theme function declared [hook_theme](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) and place your markup in your tpl.php file. (If too much markup and want your module/theme to be clean)

**Requirement 2: Add javascript**

You can use [#attached](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#attached) form/form element attribute

In the links, there are example codes that you can follow.